# "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" in DeFi tutorial app

Tags: solidity, web3js, defi

I get this error while trying to use stakingBalance method.
I think it has something to do with approval but I am not sure

here is the full error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0xcfeaaea062c38d3085a035e0fea2fce3361e1ce7b4b64d21a9de4f104debe80b": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 152,
      "return": "0x"
    },
    "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:568:26",
    "name": "RuntimeError"
  }
}
    at Object._fireError (index.js:57)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:671)
    at cb (util.js:689)
    at callbackifyOnRejected (util.js:666)
    at Item.push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:153)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:123)
```

here  are my contracts

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./DaiToken.sol";
import "./DappToken.sol";

contract TokenFarm {

  string public name = 'DApp Token Farm';
  DappToken public dappToken;
  DaiToken public daiToken;
  address public owner;
  
  address[] public stakers;
  mapping(address => uint) public stakingBalance;
  mapping(address => bool) public hasStaked;
  mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;


  constructor(DappToken _dappToken, DaiToken _daiToken) public {
    dappToken  = _dappToken;
    daiToken = _daiToken;
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
    
  // Staking Tokens (Depossiting)
  function stakeTokens (uint _amount) public {

    //validate staking amount is greater then 0
    require(_amount > 0,'amount must be greater then 0');

    //transfering Mock Dai tokens from investor(depositor)to contract(in TokenFarm)
    daiToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    
    // Update token balance for staking
    stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + _amount;

    //add invester to invstores array ONLY if he is NEW. 
    if(!hasStaked[msg.sender]){
      stakers.push(msg.sender);
    }
    //update user investor status to true
    hasStaked[msg.sender] = true;
    isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
  }

  // Issuing Tokens (interest on deopsit)
  function issueToken() public {
    //Only owner is allowed to issue tokens
    require(msg.sender == owner,'caller must be owner');

    //Issuing tokens to investors
    for (uint i=0; i<stakers.length; i++){
      address recipient = stakers[i];
      uint balance = stakingBalance[recipient];
      if(balance > 0 ){
      dappToken.transfer(recipient, balance);
      }
    }
  }

  // Unstaking Tokens (withdrawal)
  function unstakeTokens () public {
    uint balance = stakingBalance[msg.sender];
    require(balance > 0, 'account balance is 0 cannot withdraw tokens');

    //withdraw tokens and send to back to investors account
    daiToken.transfer(msg.sender, balance);

    //resert staking balance
    stakingBalance[msg.sender] = 0;

    //uodate staking status
    isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
  }

}
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DaiToken {
    string  public name = "Mock DAI Token";
    string  public symbol = "mDAI";
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000; // 1 million tokens
    uint8   public decimals = 18;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    constructor() public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DappToken {
    string  public name = "DApp Token";
    string  public symbol = "DAPP";
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000; // 1 million tokens
    uint8   public decimals = 18;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    constructor() public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is my front end :

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import './App.css';
import DaiToken from '../abis/DaiToken.json';
import DappToken from '../abis/DappToken.json';
import TokenFarm from '../abis/TokenFarm.json';

 const App = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(
    { 
      account: '0x0',
      daiToken: {},
      dappToken: {},
      tokenFarm: {},
      diaTokenBalance: '0',
      dappTokenBalance: '0',
      stakingBalance: '0',
      loading: true
    }
  );
  
  async function loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      await window.ethereum.enable();
    }
    else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    }
    else {
      window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected please install the correct extension')
    }
  }

  async function loadBlockchainData(){
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    setState(state => ({...state, account: accounts[0]}));
    const netWorkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const daiTokenData = DaiToken.networks[netWorkId];
    const dappTokenData = DappToken.networks[netWorkId];
    const tokenFarmData = DappToken.networks[netWorkId];

    // Load DiaToken
    if(daiTokenData){
      const daiToken = new web3.eth.Contract(DaiToken.abi, daiTokenData.address);
      setState(state => ({...state, daiToken: daiToken}));
      let daiTokenBalance = await daiToken.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();
      setState(state => ({...state, diaTokenBalance : daiTokenBalance.toString()}));
    }
     else{
       window.alert('DappToken contract was not depolyed to detected network');
      }

      // Load DappToken
      if(dappTokenData){
        const dappToken = new web3.eth.Contract(DappToken.abi, dappTokenData.address);
        setState(state => ({...state, dappToken: dappToken}));
        let dappTokenBalance = await dappToken.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();
        setState(state => ({...state, dappTokenBalance : dappTokenBalance.toString()}));
      }
      else{
        window.alert('DappToken contract was not depolyed to detected network');
      }

      // Load TokenFarm
      
      if(tokenFarmData){
        const tokenFarm = new web3.eth.Contract(TokenFarm.abi, tokenFarmData.address);
        setState(state => ({...state, tokenFarm: tokenFarm}));
        let stakingBalance = await tokenFarm.methods.stakingBalance(accounts[0]).call();
        setState(state => ({...state, stakingBalance : stakingBalance.toString()}));
      }
      else{
        window.alert('TokenFarm contract was not depolyed to detected network');
      }
      setState(state => ({ ...state, loading: false }));
   }
  



  useEffect(()=>{
   loadWeb3();
   loadBlockchainData(); 
  },[]);
  
  // useEffect(()=>{
  //   loadBlockchainData()
  // },[state.account]);
  
  return (
    <div>
       
          <Navbar account={state.account} />
          <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
            <div className="row">
              <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 ml-auto mr-auto" style={{ maxWidth: '600px' }}>
                <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
                  <a
                    href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                  </a>

                  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>

                </div>
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }

export default App;
```

I tried adding approve function to TokenFarm.sol

```
function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
```

and in the front end (hard coded the amount just to test) approved returned true.

```
let approved = await tokenFarm.methods.approve(accounts[0],'100000000000000000000').call();
       if(approved){...
```

here are the tests I ran

```
const { assert } = require('chai');

const DappToken = artifacts.require('DappToken');
const DaiToken = artifacts.require('DaiToken');
const TokenFarm = artifacts.require('TokenFarm');

require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should();

function tokens(x) {
  return web3.utils.toWei(x, 'ether');
}

contract('TokenFarm',([owner, investor]) => {
  let daiToken, dappToken, tokenFarm ;

  before(async ()=>{
    //Loading Contracts
    daiToken = await DaiToken.new();
    dappToken = await DappToken.new();
    tokenFarm = await TokenFarm.new(dappToken.address, daiToken.address);

    //tranfer all Dapp tokens to farm (1 mil)
    await dappToken.transfer(tokenFarm.address, tokens('1000000'));
    await daiToken.transfer(investor, tokens('100'), {from : owner });

  })
  describe('Mock DAI deployment', async () => {
    it('has a name',  async () => {
      const name = await daiToken.name()
      assert.equal(name, 'Mock DAI Token');
    });
  });
  describe('DApp Token deployment', async () => {
    it('has a name',  async () => {
      const name = await dappToken.name()
      assert.equal(name, 'DApp Token');
    });
  });
  describe('Token Farm deployment', async () => {
    it('has a name',  async () => {
      const name = await tokenFarm.name()
      assert.equal(name, 'DApp Token Farm');
    });
    it('contract has tokens', async () =>{
      let balance = await dappToken.balanceOf(tokenFarm.address);
      assert.equal(balance.toString(), tokens('1000000'));
    });

  });
  describe('token farming', async () =>{
    it('rewards investors for staking mDai tokens', async () => {
      let result

      //investor balance check prior to staking
      result = await  daiToken.balanceOf(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('100'), 'investor Mock DAI wallet doesn\'t have corret balance before staking');
      
      // Stake Moc DAI Tokens
      await daiToken.approve(tokenFarm.address, tokens('100'), { from: investor });
      await tokenFarm.stakeTokens(tokens('100'), { from: investor });
      
      // Checking staking result
      
      // Investor balance check after to staking
      result = await  daiToken.balanceOf(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('0'), 'investor Mock DAI wallet doesn\'t have corret balance after staking');
  
      result = await  daiToken.balanceOf(tokenFarm.address);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('100'), 'Token Farm Mock DAI wallet dosn\'t have corret balance after staking');
   
      result = await  tokenFarm.stakingBalance(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('100'), 'Token Farm Mock DAI wallet dosn\'t have corret balance after staking');
      
      result = await  tokenFarm.isStaking(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), 'true', 'investor status is correct after staking');

      await tokenFarm.issueToken({from : owner});
      result = await dappToken.balanceOf(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('100'), 'The balance is not correct after tokens issued');

      await tokenFarm.issueToken({from: investor}).should.be.rejected;

      // check results after unstaking
      await tokenFarm.unstakeTokens({ from: investor });
      
      
      //check that tokens were returned to investor
      result = await  daiToken.balanceOf(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('100'), 'Investor Mock DAI wallet hasn\'t been returned after unstaking');
      
      //check that balance of TokenFarm investor account is empty
      result = await  daiToken.balanceOf(tokenFarm.address);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('0'), 'Investor Mock DAI wallet isn\'t empty after unstaking');
      
      result = await  tokenFarm.stakingBalance(investor);
      assert.equal(result.toString(), tokens('0'), 'Investor Mock DAI tokenFarm isn\'t empty after unstaking');

    });
   
  });

});
```

deploy_contracts.js file

```
const DappToken = artifacts.require('DappToken');
const DaiToken = artifacts.require('DaiToken');
const TokenFarm = artifacts.require('TokenFarm');

module.exports = async function(deployer,network,accounts) {

  // Deploy Dai Token 
  await deployer.deploy(DaiToken);
  const daiToken = await  DaiToken.deployed();
  
  // Deploy Dapp Token 
  await deployer.deploy(DappToken);
  const dappToken = await  DappToken.deployed();

 // Deploy Token Farm
  await deployer.deploy(TokenFarm, dappToken.address, daiToken.address);
  const tokenFarm = await TokenFarm.deployed();

   // Tranfer all Dapp Tokens to Token Farm
  await dappToken.transfer(TokenFarm.address,'1000000000000000000000000');

   // Tranfer 100 Mock DAI Tokens to investor
   await  daiToken.transfer(accounts[1],'100000000000000000000')



};
```

Comment: It is strange `stakingBalance` is a getter function so no much reasons to fail. Is the contract deployed correctly? Is the address valid? Can you call other methods from the same contract? What solc version are you using? What's the ganache version? Are you using metamask? what's the node version? Do you have a public repo to try to reproduce?

Comment: same error trying to get hasStaked method i am adding my deploy_contracts.js file

Comment: here is my repo https://github.com/ajkatom/DeFi-React/tree/master

Comment: I tried the repo and it works as expected, it compiles fine, migrations work, tests run fine, the react app start correctly after configuring metamask with truffle develop network. I'm using node v14.18 and truffle v5.1.  I suggest to try recompiling and deploying again, check the correct address and abi are used by the frontend.

Comment: same node version downgraded truffle to 5.1 deleted abi's and recompiled  and migrated. but i still got the same error  Truffle v5.1.67 (core: 5.1.67)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.18.1
Web3.js v1.2.9

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what's wrong. The code is fine and runs without issues in my computer so there's something wrong in your computer. Some thing that may work is updating/downgrading ganache, resetting the account in metamask, using metamask with a new account in another browser.